# Is CTGetSignalStrength() a Private Method?

Tags: swift, core-telephony

I've received conflicting answers while researching this question. I am currently making use of this method from `CoreTelephony` in my app. Will my app be rejected from the app store for using it?

Comment: Anything that you don't see in SDK headers is private. SDK doesn't have headers for `CTGetSignalStrength`, so it's private and your app will be rejected.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: If you have to use dlload to get to it, (as in your question yesterday)  that's a sure sign it's private.

Comment: In this case it's a somewhat different private API. It's in a public framework. To use it you just have to define function prototype yourself.

Comment: is that to say something like this would suffice for the app store? `-(int)getSignalStrength
{
    return CTGetSignalStrength();
}`